# R data.table column names not working within a function

Tags: r, data.table, mapply

I am trying to use a data.table within a function, and I am trying to understand why my code is failing. I have a data.table as follows:

```
DT <- data.table(my_name=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),my_id=c(2,2,3,3,4,4))
> DT
   my_name my_id
1:       A     2
2:       B     2
3:       C     3
4:       D     3
5:       E     4
6:       F     4
```

I am trying to create all pairs of "my_name" with different values of "my_id", which for DT would be:

```
Var1 Var2    
A    C
A    D
A    E
A    F
B    C
B    D
B    E
B    F
C    E
C    F
D    E
D    F
```

I have a function to return all pairs of "my_name" for a given pair of values of "my_id" which works as expected.

```
get_pairs <- function(id1,id2,tdt) {
    return(expand.grid(tdt[my_id==id1,my_name],tdt[my_id==id2,my_name]))
}
> get_pairs(2,3,DT)
Var1 Var2
1    A    C
2    B    C
3    A    D
4    B    D
```

Now, I want to execute this function for all pairs of ids, which I try to do by finding all pairs of ids and then using mapply with the get_pairs function.

```
> combn(unique(DT$my_id),2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    3
[2,]    3    4    4
tid1 <- combn(unique(DT$my_id),2)[1,]
tid2 <- combn(unique(DT$my_id),2)[2,]
mapply(get_pairs, tid1, tid2, DT)
Error in expand.grid(tdt[my_id == id1, my_name], tdt[my_id == id2, my_name]) : 
  object 'my_id' not found
```

Again, if I try to do the same thing without an mapply, it works.

```
get_pairs3(tid1[1],tid2[1],DT)
Var1 Var2
1    A    C
2    B    C
3    A    D
4    B    D
```

Why does this function fail only when used within an mapply? I think this has something to do with the scope of data.table names, but I'm not sure.

Alternatively, is there a different/more efficient way to accomplish this task? I have a large data.table with a third id "sample" and I need to get all of these pairs for each sample (e.g. operating on DT[sample=="sample_id",] ). I am new to the data.table package, and I may not be using it in the most efficient way.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about why the mapply is not working and so didn't mention it in my answer.

Comment: for `mapply`, it works if you put `DT` directly into the function and not as parameter (although it doesn't solve the "why is it not working" part...)

Comment: Does each `id` always have exactly two `names`?

Comment: Each id may have one more names, and either ids or names may be duplicated. Additionally name,id pairs are not guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this function fail only when used within an mapply? I think
>   this has something to do with the scope of data.table names, but I'm
>   not sure.

The reason the function is failing has nothing to do with scoping in this case. `mapply` vectorizes the function, it takes each element of each parameter and passes to the function. So, in your case, the `data.table` elements are its columns, so `mapply` is passing the column `my_name` instead of the complete `data.table`.

If you want to pass the complete `data.table` to `mapply`, you should use the `MoreArgs` parameter. Then your function will work:

```
res <- mapply(get_pairs, tid1, tid2, MoreArgs = list(tdt=DT), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
do.call("rbind", res)
  Var1 Var2
1     A    C
2     B    C
3     A    D
4     B    D
5     A    E
6     B    E
7     A    F
8     B    F
9     C    E
10    D    E
11    C    F
12    D    F
```

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Is this because a data.table is also a list()?

Comment: @Sam Yeap, `data.table`s, `data.frame`s,  `tbl_df`s are lists with some additional properties.

Answer (score 4):

Enumerate all possible pairs

```
u_name    <- unique(DT$my_name)
all_pairs <- CJ(u_name,u_name)[V1 < V2]
```

Enumerate observed pairs

```
obs_pairs <- unique(
  DT[,{un <- unique(my_name); CJ(un,un)[V1 < V2]}, by=my_id][, !"my_id"]
)
```

Take the difference

```
all_pairs[!J(obs_pairs)]
```

`CJ` is like `expand.grid` except that it creates a data.table with all of its columns as its key. A data.table `X` must be keyed for a join `X[J(Y)]` or a not-join `X[!J(Y)]` (like the last line) to work. The `J` is optional, but makes it more obvious that we're doing a join.

---

**Simplifications.** @CathG pointed out that there is a cleaner way of constructing `obs_pairs` if you always have two sorted "names" for each "id" (as in the example data): use `as.list(un)` in place of `CJ(un,un)[V1 < V2]`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention that there may be duplicates in "my_name" but your solution works if there are no duplicates. This is much more elegant than my approach though. Clearly I need to learn to use joins more.

Comment: @Sam I've edited for that case now (if I understand it correctly).

Answer (score 4):

The function `debugonce()` is extremely useful in these scenarios.

```
debugonce(mapply)
mapply(get_pairs, tid1, tid2, DT)

# Hit enter twice
# from within BROWSER
debugonce(FUN)
# Hit enter twice
# you'll be inside your function, and then type DT
DT
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
Q # (to quit debugging mode)
```

which is wrong. Basically, `mapply()` takes the first element of each input argument and passes it to your function. In this case you've provided a *data.table*, which is also  *list*. So, instead of passing the entire data.table, it's passing each element of the list (columns).

So, you can get around this by doing:

```
mapply(get_pairs, tid1, tid2, list(DT))
```

But `mapply()` simplifies the result by default, and therefore you'd get a `matrix` back. You'll have to use `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`.

```
mapply(get_pairs, tid1, tid2, list(DT), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Or simply use `Map`:

```
Map(get_pairs, tid1, tid2, list(DT))
```

Use `rbindlist()` to bind the results.

HTH